# (C#) For xml with ":", already used XNamespace but still cannot finish parsing

Tags: c#, xml

Here is my XML content:

```
<app:DocItem Name="hello" ItemId="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" xmlns:app="xxxx">
    <app:Data>
        <cccc xmlns="yyyy" SchemaWriteVersion="1">
            <Key mClass="Tag">
                <SId Namespace="abc" ElementName="VP" />
            </Key>
            <Dictionary NId="116" Count="66">
                <Item>
                    <Key TId="7" Name="TemporaryDoNotUse" />
                    <Value Signature="....">
                    </Value>
                </Item>
            </Dictionary>
        </cccc>
    </app:Data>
</app:DocItem>
```

And here is what I'm trying in C# function:

```
    public static string GetVoicePolicy(string xmlStr)
    {
        XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(xmlStr);

        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

        XNamespace app = "app";
        XName n2 = app + "DocItem";
        XName n3 = app + "Data";

        XElement l2 = xdoc.Element(n2); //<<--------------------Line X
        XElement l3 = l2.Element(n3);
        XElement l4 = l3.Element("cccc");
        XElement l5 = l4.Element("Dictionary");
    ....
    }
```

I know for string with character ":", I cannot directly use "app:DocItem", but after using XNamespace, I still get "l2 == null" at "Line X" after it executed.

I can see content of xdoc which is correct, but l2 is just nothing. Did I miss anything?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really have

```
xmlns:app="xxxx"
```

Then you'll want

```
XNamespace app = "xxxx";
```

The name `app` is not the name of the namespace, it's just a local prefix used in that particular XML file. It could even change every time.

Comment: One more question:
for this line:
     <cccc xmlns="yyyy" SchemaWriteVersion="1">

shall I change "XElement l4 = l3.Element("cccc");" to "XElement l4 = l3.Element("yyyy");"?

Comment: No, instead you need another `XNamespace`with `yyyy` to access that one.

Comment: Thanks. I tried a new XNamespace "yyyy" but failed. And then tried this with a success:             XNamespace ll = "yyyy";
            XName lm = ll + "cccc"; XElement l4 = l3.Element(lm); ... Kind of weird.

Comment: Then after parsing l4 successfully, I get l4 = "<cccc xmlns="yyyy" SchemaWriteVersion="1">..........",next sentence XElement l5 = l4.Element("Dictionary"); failed again, since there is no xmlns definition, this should work, don't know why it failed....

Comment: `xmlns="yyyy"` also sets the namespace for any unprefixed elements inside that element - I think you should go to Google and read about how XML namespaces work so that you understand them completely.

Comment: Thanks, just figure out it during debugging, my first day playing with xml, glad to know it, thank you!